# gpg: Key generation canceled

Tags: linux, gnupg

I am having a hard time generating a gpg keypair in linux. I am following the steps in this tutorial: https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/c14.html

However, after it asks me for a passphrase and I insert one, I get the following message:

```
gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
gpg: problem with the agent: No agent running                                 
gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
gpg: problem with the agent: No agent running
gpg: Key generation canceled.
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

In shell run following command

```
kill -9 gpg-agent
source <(gpg-agent --daemon)
```

Comment: bash: kill: gpg-agent: arguments must be process or job IDs